# Safari 14.0 WebGL disabled?

Tags: safari, webgl

Safari 14.0 does indeed have WebGL enabled (see the screenshots) but I'm not able to view any WebGL pages. I seem to remember WebGL did work at some point in the past but it's totally broken now in Safari 14.

Are there any solutions to this or can other users confirm Safari 14 works at all with WebGL?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases WebGL is disabled in the Safari preferences.

AFAIK there is no UI to edit the setting. So you may need to edit the Safari property list file. It is located at

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
```

This is described in the following post:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251723774?answerId=253458486022#253458486022

The .plist can be edited with the “defaults write” command in Terminal, but this will work correctly only if Terminal has full disk access, as described in this article:

https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/containers.html

Comment: Fixed it by manually editing the plist! This is a bug in the Safari UI for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To enable WebGL 2 on Safari, one must first activate the "Develop" menu in Safari.

To do that, go to Safari Preferences > Advanced > then tick the checkbox labelled "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

After doing that, go to the Develop menu > Experimental Features > WebGL2

Voila, WebGL 2 is active.